# EAC & FLAC: The cue sheet can be applied to which file?

Tags: flac, cue-sheet, exact-audio-copy

I just encoded a CD to FLAC with the help of EAC (Exact Audio Copy) and I was wondering if the cue sheet can be used for the .wav file only or for the .flac file to? The CD is encoded into a single FLAC file; an full image of the CD. My goal is to only save the FLAC image, cue sheet and .log file for backup purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EAC would likely have produced the CUE sheet for the FLAC file only. However, if you edit the CUE sheet in a text editor (e.g. Notepad) and change the file name near the top from `filename.flac` to `filename.wav`, you can save it as a second CUE sheet which will work with the WAV file.